# MY app is not opened inside facebook its goes to my host

Tags: facebook

Hello my app is not opened inside facebook canvas. if I click on my app it just opens my app's profile page.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an application you have to define its "App Namespace" in the developers app.
You can [read more here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/).
Your application will get a url like this : http://apps.facebook.com/{your_app_namespace}
Once the user gets to that page - facebook will load your app inside an iframe.